# Flutter | Cant build my project after adding image_picker (IOS)

Tags: xcode, flutter

I got this errors when i'm building my project :

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           17,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/_s/rw7c19rs37z69qqyj97h8mjm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.lpvGma/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirtnLlA4/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
mkdir -p /Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.framework" "/Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
image_picker_ios.framework/
image_picker_ios.framework/Info.plist
image_picker_ios.framework/image_picker_ios
image_picker_ios.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 412480 bytes  received 92 bytes  825144.00 bytes/sec
total size is 412070  speedup is 1.00
Stripped /Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/image_picker_ios.framework/image_picker_ios of architectures: x86_64
Code Signing /Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/image_picker_ios.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/image_picker_ios.framework' &
/Users/romaincharles/Documents/COURSS B2/PROJET D'ETUDE/FLUTTER/INCOGNITO/incognito/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: eval: line 174: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/_s/rw7c19rs37z69qqyj97h8mjm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.lpvGma/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirtnLlA4/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Ive all my update done, flutter doctor ok and plist file also

Comment: Can you add full build logs?

Comment: @fartem this is all ive got when i build